# Using and understanding a RubyGem and its api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am trying to work with this RubyGem: https://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin

I also forked it to my github repository: https://github.com/genadinik/linkedin/

It is a wrapper for the LinkedIn API.  I am able to query it but it has too-few methods.

Here is their api:

```
https://github.com/genadinik/linkedin/blob/134fade9c4940cffad53cfe238ed21a9ad1145ee/lib/linked_in/api/query_methods.rb
```

I am trying to understand how I can add methods to that gem API so that I can add more methods.

But I don't want to necessarily add my new methods back to the original source.

Any idea how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: you had a look here: http://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-org-api/

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can work directly with your forked version from Github using Bundler: [here's](http://gembundler.com/git.html) how. You can do more development on it, and since it's on Github, you can issue pull requests to the origin if you decide you *do* have something that they might want. If you're not familiar with Bundler, you should read up on it: it's essentially a way to specify and install per-project gem dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to add your modification to your existing gem?

One way to do is add overriding sources to your initializers, for example

```
initializers/linkedin_gem_overrides.rb
```

This way, you can do whatever you want. but, you don't have organized tests and capability of catching up future upgrades.

The other way is that you also can use your forked git repository for your gem source.

Assuming you use bundler, modify linkedin gem line to yours

```
gem 'linkedin', :git => 'git://github.com/genadinik/linkedin.git'
```

By doing so, you can organize gems with tests on your way, but you may lose the upgrade of original gem.

I recommend that if you are satisfied your own modification (WITH FULL TESTS!!!), send the author pull requests. Once the author accept your change, you can simply remove that line back to use rubygems.org.

```
gem 'linkedin'
```